How to find missing byte of 32 bit value of linear recursion in C?
I am working on an improved PKZIP key generation based on PKCRACK.
My aim is to generate key2 candidate that are far less that 4 million given three consecutive plaintext bytes based on this code:
static void updateKeys( uint8_t plainbyte, uint32_t *key )
{
    uint16_t temp;
    key[0] = CRC32( key[0], plainbyte );
    key[1] = (key[1] + (key[0]&0xff))*CONSTx + 1;
    key[2] = CRC32( key[2], MSB(key[1]) );
    temp = (key[2]&0xffff) | 3;
    key[3] = ((temp * (temp^1))>>8)&0xff;
}

For each given plaintext i can get key3 and from that key3 i can get 256 possible last 16 bits of key2 for that position like this:
void gen_key2(int n) {
    int i, j, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, z = 0, t = 0, u = 0;
    uint8_t key3a, key3b, key3c;
    uint16_t keym, lk, bt;
    uint32_t tmpkeyb, tmpkeya, key2a, key2b, rest[256][10];
    uint8_t lk_b[256] = {0}, lk_c[256] = {0};
    uint16_t ls16a[256], ls16b[256], ls16c[256],tap[256];  
    // Load `key3` values for positions
    key3a = KEY3(n);
    key3b = KEY3(n - 1);
    key3c = KEY3(n - 2);
    // Populate last 16-bit key2 candidates
    for (uint16_t x = 0xFFF; x < 0xFFFF; x++) {
        keym = x | 3;  // Ensure the lower 2 bits are set
        lk = ((keym * (keym ^ 1)) >> 8) & 0xFF;       
        // Check if this `lk` matches one of our `key3` values
        if (lk == key3a) {
            ls16a[a++] = x;
            tap[x&0xFF] = x;
        } else if (lk == key3b) {
            ls16b[b++] = x;
            lk_b[x >> 8]++;  // Count occurrences of the first byte of `ls16b`
        } else if (lk == key3c) {
            ls16c[c++] = x;
            lk_c[x >> 8]++;  // Count occurrences of the first byte of `ls16c`
        }
    }
    // Build `tempkeya` and `tempkeyb` lists with correct MSB and LSB
    for (i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
            uint32_t crc = crctab[i];
            uint8_t dfb = (crc ^ ls16a[j]) & 0xFF;
            uint8_t dfc = (crc ^ ls16b[j]) & 0xFF;

            if (lk_b[dfb] > 3 && (crc>>24)> 0) {  // Check if `dfb` is valid
                tempkeya[t++] = (crc & 0xFF000000) | ls16a[j];
            }
            if (lk_c[dfc] > 3 && (crc>>24)> 0) {  // Check if `dfc` is valid                
                tempkeyb[u++] = (crc & 0xFF000000) | ls16b[j]; 
            }
        }
 
    }
    printf("Total tempkeysb : %d  tempkeysa : %d\n", u, t);
}

And now i have 2 lists of key2 values that have first byte and last 2 bytes correct, leaving the second byte missing, But i think these 2 lists can solve each other's missing byte but i couldn't make it work in code but on paper it works and that is why i am here.
I have list1 with 14384 values missing second byte and list2 with 14384 values missing second byte but the equation key2_i = key2_{i-1}>>8 ^ crctab[x_i] states that these values are related,  meaning
bt = (crcbymsb[tempkeya[j] >> 24] ^ tempkeya[j]) & 0xFFFF;

Last byte of bt is the third byte of the value in tempkeyb[] and the first byte of bt is the missing byte of that value in tempkeyb[].
I couldn't get this to work, like just finding the missing byte without additional workload.
If i iterate through crctab[] form 0 to 255 then xor each value with a value from tempkeyb[], i get 2 million keys with correct key in it but 2 million from 14384 is not acceptable, the highest acceptable amount is around 60000 because in the 256 possible 16 bit of key2 per each key3 those 16 bit values can also be grouped based on their first 8 bits and they become just 64. so given any key2's third byte, they are 4 possible fourth byte for that given 3rd byte.
